# Redirect one local url to an arbitrary url for local development ease. Windows hosts file?

Tags: dns, cname, hosts

I have an application running on https://localhost:5001

I'd like this application to be navigatable from a browser by plugging in something like `helpful-tools.com`.

What are my options?

I've tried a few variations in the windows' `hosts` file to no avail:

- `127.0.0.1:5001 helpful-tools.com localhost:5001`
- `127.0.0.1:5001 localhost helpful-tools.com`
- `127.0.0.1 localhost:5001 helpful-tools.com`
- `127.0.0.1 helpful-tools.com localhost:5001`

Comment: `hosts` file as its name implies is only for hostnames. You can't have ports in that file.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Good to know.